# Tableau : Calculed field to transform series of odd numbers to a sequence of numbers

Tags: tableau-api

I need your help with the formulation for a calculed a field in Tableau (Tableau Prep to be accurate).

I have a field called [Code Order] which contains only a series of Odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9,..) multiple times, which means it can be `(1,3,1,3,5,7,1,1,1,3,5,7,9,11)`.

What I need is to transform these in a normal sequence of numbers so for my example above I need as a result: `(1,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6)`

In other words when in [Code Order] I have :

```
1 = 1
3 = 2
5 = 3
7 = 4
9 = 5
11 = 6
13 = 7
15 = 8
...
365 = 183
```

For the moment my maximum is 365, which is position 183, I would like to avoid to type 182 IF formulas if possible. ;)

Thanks in advance for your help.
CYA

Plt.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might turn out to be more accurate in case your `Code Order` series is missing any values along the way.

**Example series:**

[image]

**Alternate Field:**

[image]

**Tableau Setup:**

[image]

Comment: This is even better and works perfectly. I usually run a query out of Tableau to do correction of the data to avoid ensure that the numbers are indeed following but with your solution you optimize my problematic and I can avoid outside treatment. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the index() calculated field. Create a new field called `index`. The calculation is just `index()`.

[image]

Add `[Code Order]` to your row shelf and `index` to your label. You should see something like this.

[image]

Comment: This will only give the right answer if there are no gaps in your sequence. If you filter out Code Order 7 for instance. Then the index for Code Order 9 will be 4 instead of 5

Answer (score 0):

The following calculation should do the trick

```
CEILING([Code Order] / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment on @Vizyourdata which helped me out. I also tried your formula but I don't understand why sometimes it doesn't "react" how it should. When I have a 1 with ceiling formula sometimes it gets a 2 and a 3 gets a 4 not a 2, another case 1 gets 3, 3 gets 4, 5 gets 3 and 7 gets 4. I'm a bit confused. The Round(AVG) formula works fine for me. So for me it's good so far. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ceiling() rounds a number up to the nearest integer. Floor() rounds down, I.e. truncates, to the nearest integer. So Ceiling(3/2) should always be 2. If you find otherwise, you may have found a bug. Floor() and Ceiling() are available in many, but not all, data sources. If you can reproduce wrong results for Ceiling(), please send to Tableau support so they can fix it. But if round() is working for you, then great - though you may not need to call AVG() also as in the answer .